# result of coupled ODE in python code is different from mathematica

Tags: python, wolfram-mathematica

As per my language knowledge my code is written correct. But It is not giving me correct solution (plot). When I had solved same system of ODE's  in mathematica, I have correct solution and both solutions are totally different. I am writing a research project so I need a proper code in python. could you please let me know the mistake of mine code. 
[python code solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B9vhE.png)
[Mathematica solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/djLRv.png)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.integrate as si
##Three system
def func(state, T):
    H = state[0]
    P = state[1]
    R = state[2]
    Hd = -(16./3.)*np.pi*P 
    Pd = -4.*H*P
    Rd = H*R
    return Hd,Pd,Rd
T = np.linspace(0.1,0.9,50)
state0 = [1,0.0001, 0.1]
s = si.odeint(func, state0, T)
h = np.transpose(s)
plt.plot(T,h[0])
plt.show()
```

Mathematica code

```
Clear[H,\[Rho],a]
Eq1=(H'[t] == -16 \[Pi] \[Rho][t]/3)
Eq2= (\[Rho]'[t] == -4 H[t] \[Rho][t])
Eq3 = (a'[t] ==  H[t] a[t])
sol=NDSolve[{Eq1,Eq2, Eq3,
     H[0.1]==0.1, \[Rho][0.1]==0.1, a[0.1]==0.1}, 
       {H[t],\[Rho][t],a[t]}, {t,0.1, 0.9}]
Plot[Evaluate[{H[t]}/.sol],{t,0.1,0.9}]
```

[image]

Comment: for starters you have a different initial condition and a different time domain, and then I'm sure you'll need more than 10 points to get any sort of accuracy.  You also have a different expression for H'.. the python version has an extra `1/R^2` term

Comment: Trust me I did it for 1000 points even , and with and without 1/R**2

Comment: Is it possible to edit question then I can show you the exact like mathematica (its by mistaken I added wrong! )

Comment: is it possible to edit

Comment: you fixed the one thing but still have different initial conditions (`state0`) and domain (`0-10`) vs (`.1-.9`)

Comment: Please use the [edit] link here or below your post rather than [asking the same question again](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38059689/result-of-coupled-ode-in-python-code-is-different-from-mathematica-solution).

Comment: yes I had edited, it yesterday itself. Since i need solution badly and it was not editing , I made a duplicated. But now I deleted that.

Comment: could anyone try to answer my question instead of finding errors in me :( :'(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both codes are correct, I just turned off my laptop and on it again, and it gives me the correct result (as mathematica)